# Rails current url helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url

Apologies for such a simple question, but I couldn't been able to solve it myself after hours since my RoR knowledge is basically nonexistent. In the Rails application I'm working with, has been used a navigation helper to highlight active menu:

```
  def nav_link(link_text, link_path, ico_path)
    class_name = current_page?(link_path) ? 'active' : nil

    content_tag :li do
      link_to(link_path, class: class_name) do
        image_tag("icons/#{ico_path}.svg") + content_tag(:span, link_text)
      end
    end
  end
```

The circumstances have changed and `current_page?` is no longer a viable option, since routing now handled on the front-end. Is there a way to achieve the same functionality by retrieving, for instance, current url and check it against `link_path`?. I've tried a lot of things with different helpers like `request.original_url`, but to no avail.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't check against the current controller? I.e. I use `controller.class == GraphsController` to highlight navigation items, but it's possible I'm misunderstanding your question.

Comment: @Undo, I'm really in the dark here, but common sense tells me that I would need a helper like `current_controller` in order to make it work. Or hardcode each state of being `active` for each menu separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`request.original_url` should work according to the documentation.

> Returns the original request URL as a string

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Request/original_url

You could also try string concatenation with different variables.

```
request.host + request.full_path
```

If that doesn't work either, you could try

`url_for(:only_path => false)`;

Comment: It's not that it doesn't work, I really just don't know how to incorporate it in the helper I have. As far as I understand `current_page` accepted `link_path` as argument and `?` operator has been used to retrieve Boolean value and assign `active` to `class_name` variable if `true`. `request.original_url` or `url_for(:only_path => false)` accepts no arguments, but I think it does returns a URL, I just don't use it properly. Thanks for your input, @RichardHamilton

Comment: Related: careful redirecting to the result of `url_for` with `only_path: false` and user-generated input as you open yourself up to open-redirect attacks. E.g. when a malicious user sends his victim a link to `/foo/bar/?host=www.example.com`. Rails will redirect them to www.example.com.

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
request.url
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Http/URL.html#method-i-url

or

```
request.path
```

http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rack/Rack/Request#path-instance_method

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to look at the [`active_link_to`](https://github.com/comfy/active_link_to) gem:

```
def nav_link(link_text, link_path, ico_path)
    content_tag :li do
      active_link_to link_path do
        image_tag("icons/#{ico_path}.svg") + content_tag(:span, link_text)
      end
    end
end
```

Unlike the `current_page?` helper, `active_link_to` uses controller actions and model objects to determine whether you're on a specific page.

`current_page?` only tests against the current path, leaving you exposed if you're dealing with obscure or ajaxified routes.

--

I was going to write about how `current_page?` works etc, but since you mentioned that it's nonviable, I won't. I would have to question *why* it's nonviable though...

> routing now handled on the front-end.

Surely even if you're using something like Angular with Rails, you'd have to set the routes for your app?

Comment: I'm using Backbone to navigate between pages, all routes declared and scoped properly in routes.rb, but the actual routing is now performed via JS, so the only interaction with Rails is the GET request on the relevant route. I would've just moved this logic over to Backbone as well, but this menu contains things that are better left int the `erb`, authorization handling and such. Active link has worked (it assigns 'active' on first load), but it doesn't respond to GET requests. Maybe what I'm trying to do is just not achievable? @RichPeck